# For every $\alpha >1$, show that $\frac {\max\{X_1, \ldots ,X_n\}}{n^a} \rightarrow 0$ with probability 1

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $E(X^2_1)<+\infty$, then for every $\alpha >1$ show that $\frac {\max\{X_1, \ldots ,X_n\}}{n^a} \rightarrow 0$ ,with probability 1.

I am trying to prove this but with no luck yet.
I would appreciate any kind of hints.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hint: $\max \{X_1,\cdots,X_n\} \leq \sum_{k=1}^n |X_k|$

Comment: @lc2r43 i have tried use it but i am not sure how can i proceed.

Answer (score 5):

We have that $\max \{ X_ 1, \cdots , X_n\} \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{n}|X_k|$. By the strong form of the Law of Large Numbers:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n |X_k| \to \mathbb{E}[|X|]<\infty \quad \text{ almost surely}
$$
Thus:$$\frac{\max \{ X_ 1, \cdots , X_n\}}{n^\alpha} = 
\frac{\max \{ X_ 1, \cdots , X_n\}}{n \cdot n^{\alpha-1}} \leq \frac{1}{n^{\alpha - 1}} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n |X_k| \to0 \quad \text{Almost surely}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Can someone see if my solution is on the right track?

Let $f$ be the common pdf shared among the random variables stated in the problem, and suppose $X \sim f$. We will first show $E(|X|)$ exists. Notice how $$0\leq\int_{|x|>1}|x|f(x)dx \leq \int _{|x|>1}x^2f(x)dx\leq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x)dx=E(X^2)<\infty$$
This proves $\int_{|x|>1}|x|f(x)dx$ converges, and since $$0\leq\int_{|x| \leq 1}|x|f(x)dx \leq \int_{|x|\leq 1}f(x)dx=P(|X| \leq 1)<\infty$$ we see that$$0\leq\int_{|x| \leq 1}|x|f(x)dx+\int_{|x|>1}|x|f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|f(x)dx=E(|X|)$$ exists. This also implies $V(|X|)$ exists since $$V(|X|)=E(|X|^2)-(E(|X|))^2=E(X^2)-(E(|X|))^2<\infty$$
Set $\mu=E(|X|)$ and $\sigma^2=V(|X|)$, and choose $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily. Since $$|\max\{X_1,..,X_n\}|\leq \max\{|X_1|,...,|X_n|\}\leq \sum_{j=1}^n|X_j|$$ we have by the central limit theorem for large $n$ that $$P\Bigg(\frac{|\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}|}{n^{\alpha}}\leq \epsilon\Bigg)\geq P\Bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n|X_j|\leq\epsilon n^{\alpha-1}\Bigg) \approx P\Bigg(Z\leq\frac{\sqrt{n}(\epsilon n^{\alpha-1}-\mu)}{\sigma}\Bigg)$$ Here $Z \sim N(0,1)$. Take $n \rightarrow \infty$ to get $$P\Bigg(\frac{|\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}|}{n^{\alpha}}\leq \epsilon\Bigg) \rightarrow 1$$ Am I on the right track?

Comment: It is better to use the law of large numbers in in this case, rather than the central limit theorem.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I need to become more comfortable using these theorems to solve problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer guys , i know i am being late i am sorry but a reminder is given: that the probability density function of gamma distribution $G(a,n)$ where $a>0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$  is $f(x)=\frac{a^n}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1} e ^ {-ax}$  where $x>0$  . Is there any way to prove the convergence by using that ? ( there is a chance that this reminder is for another exercise of the sheet , i am just a bit confused)

Comment: @Soer If $X_1, \cdots , X_n$ are IID uniform random variables, then the distribution of the max of $X_1, \cdots , X_n$ has a PDF given by the gamma distribution.

Comment: @rubikscube09 oh thats really helpful indeeed, but how do we include that to the solution tho since the  Law of Large Numbers only requires r.v which they are  independent and identically distributed

Comment: @Soer If the variates $X_1, \cdots , X_n$ are continuous, you can transform them to a uniform distribution using the distribution function (cdf)